# Positing child div without expending parent div

Tags: css, html, position

I would like to define the following child div position.

```
|-------------------|
|  parent div       |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|    |-------|      |
|    |  child|      |
|    |  div  |      |
-----|       |------|
     |-------|
```

I am using relative position to define the position of the child div but it expands the

```
|-------------------| 
|  parent div       |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|    |-------|      |
|    |  child|      |
|    |  div  |      |
|    |       |      |
|----|-------|------|
```

I wonder how I can position the child div without expanding the height of the parent div.

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can done it using relative positioning of child div

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.parent
{
    background-color:green;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
.child
{
    position:relative;
    top:350px;
    left:200px;
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

you can set color and width as per requirement.
Have a look [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDEBX/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I make a div relative to another without nest them?

Comment: Relative positioning means relative to it's parent. So whatever you are given the value of left,right etc. will calculates from parent div. and please mark it as answer. :)

Comment: @YangYang if you have any other problem or issue than feel free to ask.?